# Magento 2.3.2 download

Tags: magento2, installation, server-setup

Can any body provide me fresh installation for magento 2.3.2.
Every time i tried with the setup installtion it gives me error.
Can anybody provide me with fresh setup of version 2.3.2

Getting this error

```
[2020-02-27 07:20:45] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento0_wazoodle02.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento0_wazoodle02.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` at /home/magento02wsisit/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento0_wazoodle02.core_config_data' doesn't exist at /home/magento02wsisit/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

Comment: which error you are facing during installation ? you can download here: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Comment: please add error in question

Comment: Attached the error screen shot.

Comment: added the error in question

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

- Go to https://magento.com/tech-resources/download
- Click on **Release Archive** tab
- Find **ver 2.3.2** and choose appropriate format (i.e. zip/tar.gz/tar.bz2)
- Click on the Download button.

Note: For this process, you need to be logged into magento.com website.

**Option 2:**

- Go to https://www.mageplaza.com/download-magento/
- Find **Magento 2.3.2** and click on either **Download .zip file** or **Download .tar.gz**

**Note:** For Magento 2.3.2, there is a patch version also available. Please check before downloading.

**Edit:** After checking the error posted in the edited question, it seems that the Magento installation process was not completed correctly. Before installing Magento again, first, drop all tables installed previously and check the Collation is utf8 or not.